# Serving tensorflow model as a REST API in Flask / Bottle

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm serving my tensorflow model in a Python bottle(or flask) framework but I would like to know how to enable the GPU.

This is how Im creating the session.

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        np_pred_confs, np_pred_boxes = sess.run([pred_confs, pred_boxes], feed_dict=feed_dict_testing)
```

What should be changed to enable the use of the GPU as I'm running the code on a GPU machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need nothing extra to use GPU but just installing GPU version tensorflow. It will automatically use gpu. Further, you need install cuda and cudnn for GPU version tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from installing the GPU version of TensorFlow, you also need to install:

1. the necessary GPU drivers - and specifically NVIDIA only
2. [CUDA Toolkit 8.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) and
3. [cuDNN v6 or v6.1](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) (select *"Download cuDNN v6.0 (April 27, 2017), for CUDA 8.0"*)

See the per-OS install notes:

- [requirements to run TensorFlow with GPU support, on Ubuntu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#nvidia_requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support)
- [requirements to run TensorFlow with GPU support, on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support)
- TensorFlow with GPU support is not available on Mac

You'll know that it's working correctly if you see this when you run the getting started example](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started#complete_program):

> ```
> Found device 0 with properties:
> name: GeForce GTX...
> ```

and

> ```
> Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX
> ```